# Linear phase and stability of a filter

Tags: signal-processing

I have a question that says that a system has N poles which are placed on the plane:
$$ {{|z-0.75\,e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}|<0.25}} $$ and I am asked if the system is stable and if it has a linear phase. I don't quite understand this kind of writing and I would be glad for an explanation.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which system  you intend to analyze?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention this is an LTI system

Comment: there are definitions for what a "linear phase filter" is and what a "stable filter" is. Are you following a text that covers these topics?